# Assign weight and rate to products based on size of variety & weight

Tags: postgresql, weighted, rate

I have table1

| line | products | product variety | weight | rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 49 |  |  |
| 2 | b | 27 |  |  |
| 3 | c | 26 |  |  |
| 4 | d | 28 |  |  |
| 5 | e | 7 |  |  |
| 6 | f | 6 |  |  |
| 7 | g | 7 |  |  |
| 8 | h | 13 |  |  |
| 9 | i | 12 |  |  |
| 10 | j | 13 |  |  |
| 11 | k | 13 |  |  |
| 12 | l | 3 |  |  |
| 13 | m | 6 |  |  |
| 14 | n | 13 |  |  |
| 15 | o | 5 |  |  |
| 16 | p | 5 |  |  |
| 17 | q | 10 |  |  |
| 18 | r | 707 |  |  |
| 19 | s | 26 |  |  |
| 20 | t | 10 |  |  |
| 21 | u | 10 |  |  |
| 22 | v | 10 |  |  |
| 23 | w | 5 |  |  |
| 24 | x | 2 |  |  |
| 25 | y | 2 |  |  |
| 26 | z | 2 |  |  |

Want to assign weight to each products based on the size of **product variety** and rate will be calculated based on the **weight** like, the 1st largest weight = 1, the 2nd largest weight = 2 and so on. The total sum of weights should be 100

The expected result looks like below

| line | products | product variety | weight | rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 49 | 6.38 | 2 |
| 2 | b | 27 | 5.40 | 4 |
| 3 | c | 26 | 5.34 | 5 |
| 4 | d | 28 | 5.46 | 3 |
| 5 | e | 7 | 3.19 | 9 |
| 6 | f | 6 | 2.94 | 10 |
| 7 | g | 7 | 3.19 | 9 |
| 8 | h | 13 | 4.20 | 6 |
| 9 | i | 12 | 4.07 | 7 |
| 10 | j | 13 | 4.20 | 6 |
| 11 | k | 13 | 4.20 | 6 |
| 12 | l | 3 | 1.80 | 12 |
| 13 | m | 6 | 2.94 | 10 |
| 14 | n | 13 | 4.20 | 6 |
| 15 | o | 5 | 2.64 | 11 |
| 16 | p | 5 | 2.64 | 11 |
| 17 | q | 10 | 3.77 | 8 |
| 18 | r | 707 | 10.75 | 1 |
| 19 | s | 26 | 5.34 | 5 |
| 20 | t | 10 | 3.77 | 8 |
| 21 | u | 10 | 3.77 | 8 |
| 22 | v | 10 | 3.77 | 8 |
| 23 | w | 5 | 2.64 | 11 |
| 24 | x | 2 | 1.14 | 13 |
| 25 | y | 2 | 1.14 | 13 |
| 26 | z | 2 | 1.14 | 13 |

Tried in excel with the below formulas and is working perfectly, but i want something like this in postgresql to provide same above result.

```
D2=LOG10(C2)/SUM(LOG10($C$2:$C$27))*100
E2=SUMPRODUCT(($D2 < $D$2:$D$27)/COUNTIF($D$2:$D$27,$D$2:$D$27))+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate weights in the inner query and use the window function `dense_rank()`:

```sql
select 
    line, 
    products, 
    product_variety,
    weight,
    dense_rank() over (order by weight desc) as rate
from (
    select
        line, 
        products, 
        product_variety,
        round(log(product_variety::dec)/ sum* 100, 2) as weight
    from table1
    cross join lateral (
        select sum(log(product_variety::dec))
        from table1 
        ) s
    ) s
order by line
```

Test the query in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/qbHD0Axl)

Comment: See also [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4XjPAO8V) if you don't know how to update a table from a query.

Comment: @ klin can we have two separate codes to update weight & rate please. thanks

Comment: @Gulya - of course, no problem: [fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/6d40WfzG)